# What is the difference between a Categorical Column and a Dense Column?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

In Tensorflow, there are 9 different *feature columns*, arranged into three groups: *categorical*, *dense* and *hybrid*.

From reading the [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/feature_columns), I understand categorical columns are used to represent *discrete* input data with a numerical value. It gives the example of a categorical column called *categorical identity column*:

```
ID   Represented using one-hot encoding
0    [1, 0, 0, 0]
1    [0, 1, 0, 0]
2    [0, 0, 1, 0]
3    [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

But you also have a dense column called *indicator* column, which 'wraps'(?) a categorical column to produce something that looks almost identical:

```
Category (from category column)   Represented as...
0                                 [1, 0, 0, 0]
1                                 [0, 1, 0, 0]
2                                 [0, 0, 1, 0]
3                                 [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

So both 'categorical' and 'dense' columns seems to be able to represent discrete data, and both can use one-hot encoding, so that's not what distinguishes one from another.

My question is: ***In principle***, what are the difference between a 'categorical column' and a 'dense column'?

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this before finding an answer on the DataScience StackExchange,
you can find the original answer [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/29863/difference-between-indicator-column-and-categorical-identity-column-in-tensorflow)

If i understood correctly the answer is simply that while the categorical column will indeed encode the data as `one-hot` the `indicatorcolumn` will encode it as `multi-hot`